# Replace words that are common in two text file with third word

Tags: python, replace

i have two text file 1.txt is dictionary of words, and other is 2.txt with phrases now i would like to check the common words in 1.txt & 2.txt and i want to replace those common words with a third word "explain".

i have tried many ways to crack but failed. can any one help me

code i have used:

```
wordsreplace = open("1.txt",'r')

with open("2.txt") as main:
    words = main.read().split()

replaced = []
for y in words:
    if y in wordreplace:
        replaced.append(wordreplace[y])
    else:
        replaced.append(y)
text = ' '.join(replaced)

replaced = []
for y in words:
    replacement = wordreplace.get(y, y)
    replaced.append(replacement)
text = ' '.join(replaced)

text = ' '.join(wordreplace.get(y, y) for y in words)

new_main = open("2.txt", 'w')
new_main.write(text)
new_main.close()
```

this code writes the 2.txt but i cannot words replaced

Comment: it would be better if you posted that files content and expected result

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to point out problems in your code, because this task can be basically done in a few lines. Here's a self-contained example (no files, only text input)

- first create a `set` called `words` you can lookup into when needed (passing `read().split()` to a `set()` will do when done from a file: `words = set(main.read().split())`)
- now use a *word-boundary word regex* and a *replacement function*

The replacement function issues the word if not found in the dictionary else, it issues "explain":

```
words = {"computer","random"}

text = "computer sometimes yields random results"

import re

new_text = re.sub(r"\b(\w+)\b",lambda m : "explain" if m.group(1) in words else m.group(1),text)

print(new_text)
```

So the replacement is handled by the regex engine, calling my `lambda` when there's a match, so I can decide whether to replace the word, or issue it back again.

result:

```
explain sometimes yields explain results
```

Of course this doesn't handle plurals (computers, ...) which must be in the dictionary as well.